# What options are available for Sorcerers (or other spontaneous casters) to increase their daily number of spell slots?

Tags: spellcasting, pathfinder-2e, sorcerer, spell-slots

I'm trying to find a hopefully exhaustive list of all of the potential methods for increasing the number of spells per day a Sorcerer (or other spontaneous spellcaster, but I'm mostly interested in Sorcerer) can cast.

In previous editions and other flavours of d20 games there were quite a lot of options, but now in PF2e I can only find the listed options below:

- Ring of Wizardry (restricted to Arcane tradition only)
- Ring of Counterspells (arguable, kindof a spellslot but very limited)
- Staves

Have I missed any?  Is there any listed quote or intention as to why spontaneous spell casters get what appears to be so few of them, and even LESS for non-arcane casters? (might be off topic, I admit, but if you're not arcane you get basically staves and that's it?).

I'm not counting Wands or Scrolls or similar "use this and get a specific spell" items as part of this question, as they don't require or benefit you specifically as a spontaneous spell caster.

Comment: I think this one is probably fine, but see these meta posts for our guidance on list questions: [Are "list questions" on topic?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/176), [What are list questions?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6442)

Comment: @Ben are you interested in things like spellcasting archetypes, which give you more spells? These aren't Sorcerer spells, but they are feats a Sorcerer could take which give the Sorcerer more spells to cast. (If not, I'd expect the options to be very limited).

Comment: If the archetypes are spontaneous, sure.  I don't think I'd consider "also be a wizard" to count for having more spontaneous spells available.  I should have remembered Wellspring Mage, and actually Cathartic Mage as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's actually quite a few options which grant extra spell slots to spontaneous casters, though most are gated behind specific classes/requirements.

I've also pulled out a few abilities that grant additional spells that aren't wands/scrolls as worth being mentioned for this.

### Extra Spell Slots

- [Bloodline Breadth](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=739) 8th-level Sorcerer Archetype Feat

  - Bonus lower-level spell slots
- *[Candle of Invocation](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=709)* 16th-level Consumable

  - 2 bonus low-level spell slots
- [Conscious Spell Specialization](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=3685) 14th-level Psychic Feat

  - Bonus spell slots for conscious mind spells
- [Divine Effusion](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1508) 18th-level Oracle Feat

  - Ignore empty spell slots twice, different levels
- [Divine Evolution](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=611) 4th-level Sorcerer Feat

  - Bonus highest-level spell slot, only *harm* or *heal*
- [*Divine Inspiration*](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=83) 8th-level Spell

  - Recover spent up to 6th-level spell slot
- [Greater Vital Evolution](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=627) 16th-level Sorcerer Feat

  - Ignore empty spell slots twice, different levels
- [Master Summoner](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=2912) 6th-level Summoner Feat

  - Split spell slot into two for only summoning/incarnate spells
- [Mysterious Breadth](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1856) 8th-level Oracle Archetype Feat

  - Bonus lower-level spell slots
- [Mystery Conduit](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1509) 20th-level Oracle Feat

  - Unlimited 5th-level or lower spell slots, each increasing curse
- [Occult Breadth](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=683) 8th-level Bard Archetype Feat

  - Bonus lower-level spell slots
- [Primal Evolution](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=611) 4th-level Sorcerer Feat

  - Bonus highest-level spell slot, only *summon animal/plant/fungus*
  - Or with [Greater Physical Evolution](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1825) 12th-level Feat, any polymorph battle-form spell
- [*Return to Essence*](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=1087) 7th-level Spell

  - Disarm magical lock/trap and recover spent spell slot up to 3rd-level
  - Recover up to 6th-level if cast as a 10th-level spell
- [*Ring of Wizardry*](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=462) 7th-level Item

  - 2-3 bonus low-level spell slots
- [Sepulchral Sublimation](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=3485) 14th-level Reanimator Archetype Feat

  - Destroy undead minion to not spend spell slot
  - Non-duration spells only, only up to half destroyed creature's level
- [Spell Battery](https://2e.aonprd.com/Familiars.aspx?ID=17) Familiar Ability

  - One extra low-level spell slot, requires access to 4th-level spells
- [Studious Capacity](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=207) 16th-level Bard Feat

  - Ignore empty spell slot, not highest level
- [*Umbral Extraction*](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=1022) 2nd-level Spell

  - Steal spell slot from other creature
- [Wellspring Mage](https://2e.aonprd.com/Archetypes.aspx?ID=104) Class Archetype

  - Less spell slots, but often one free spell slot per encounter
  - Initially limited 2x per day, at level 2 it's unlmited

### Extra Spells

- [Absorb Spell](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1138) 14th-level Spellmaster Feat

  - Cast a spell that you critically succeeded a save against once within 10 minutes
  - With 18th-level feat [Retain Absorbed Spell](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=2249) can cast three times within 1 hour
- [Echoing Spell](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1831) 18th-level Sorcerer Feat

  - Can cast 4th-level, no-duration spells twice over two turns from spell slots
- [Loaner Spell](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1797) 8th-level Rogue Feat

  - Cast one 3rd-level or lower spell loaned from another caster
- [Second Chance Spell](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1842) 18th-level Wizard Feat

  - Cast enchantment spell again on different creature after first critically succeeded save
  - Would need to be a wizard with a spontaneous-casting archetype for this question, but would work there
- [Spell Gem](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=3518) 16th-level Lich Feat

  - One extra spell cast without spending spell slot, from a specific list of spells

Comment: Thanks, that sort of thing is exactly what I was looking for!  I realize I'd missed Wellspring Mage somehow (given its entire THING is getting back spellslots) later in the day after asking, but you've found so many things I've never heard of!  I really should have remembered the familiar abilities though.  Still surprised there's so few items nowadays, but I knew I was missing feats.